# Does there exist a function with the following periodicity properties?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I am looking for a non-zero smooth function on $\mathbb R^2$ with the following periodicity properties

$$f(x_1,x_2) =e^{-i\pi x_2} f(x_1+1,x_2) \text{ and } f(x_1,x_2) =e^{i\pi x_1} f(x_1,x_2+1).$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos nothing

Comment: @Hyperplane sorry, non-zero function

Comment: Do you also require some sort of $x_1 \leftrightarrow x_2$ symmetry? If not, $f(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi (x_1-n)^2} e^{2\pi i (n x_2-x_1 x_2/2)}$ seems to work.

Comment: When you write $f=\rho\cdot u$ with $\rho(x_1,x_2)>0$ and $|u(x_1,x_2)|=1$ you see that $\rho$ simply has to periodic mod ${\mathbb Z}^2$. The map $u:\>{\mathbb R}^2\to S^1$ incorporates the given conditions (and remains a mystery).